# Error reloading project with IJ and Gradle 6.5

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I try to reload my project with Gradle in IntelliJ I get a failure.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\yateu\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\yateu\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  initialization script 'C:\Users\yateu\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle': 4: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
   @ line 4, column 1.
     import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
     ^
  
  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57ms
```

This happens with IJ 2020.2EAP (202.5958.24), Gradle 6.5(.1), OpenJDK 14.

- Switching to IJ 2020.1.2 leads to the same problem.
- Switching to Gradle 6.4.1 works fine.
- I also tried to use a very basic build.gradle by just applying the java plugin but got the same error.

The first few lines of the ijinit.gradle is the following (and we can see the import that fails):

```
import org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectInternal
import org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilderRegistry
import org.gradle.util.GradleVersion
import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder

import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList

initscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath files(["F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24.plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-gradle-tooling.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/lib/util.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-gradle-tooling.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24.plugins/Minecraft Development/lib/MinecraftDev-2020.2-1.4.1-gradle-tooling-extension.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-rt.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24.plugins/Kotlin/lib/kapt3-idea.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24.plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24.plugins/Kotlin/lib/noarg-ide-plugin.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/lib/ion-java-1.5.2-2.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24.plugins/Kotlin/lib/allopen-ide-plugin.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/lib/external-system-rt.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24.plugins/Kotlin/lib/sam-with-receiver-ide-plugin.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/plugins/gradle-ext/lib/gradle-ext-profiler-tooling.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.70.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/lib/trove4j.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar","F:/Programmes/Jetbrains/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.5958.24/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-impldep-6.5.jar"])
  }
}

apply plugin: JetGradlePlugin
[...]
```

Is it a problem with my current IJ installation or Gradle 6.5 is simply not supported?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT
The actual build.gradle that I'm using:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.0.0'
    id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version '0.28.0'
    id 'com.novoda.build-properties' version '0.4.1'
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version '5.1.0'
}

def secretsFile = new File(".", "secrets.properties")

if (!secretsFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
    secretsFile.mkdirs()
}

if (!secretsFile.exists()) {
    secretsFile.withWriterAppend { w ->
        w << "\n"
    }
}

buildProperties {
    secrets {
        using(file('secrets.properties')).or(System.getenv()).or([
                "GITHUB_USER" : "RakSrinaNa",
                "GITHUB_TOKEN": "N/A"
        ])
    }
}

group = 'fr.raksrinana'
description = 'RSNDiscord'
sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14

mainClassName = project.mainClass

dependencies {
    implementation("net.dv8tion:JDA:${project.JDA_version}") {
        exclude module: 'opus-java'
    }
    implementation("com.sedmelluq:lavaplayer:${project.lavaplayer_version}")
    implementation("com.github.natanbc:lavaplayer-arm-natives:${project.lavaplayer_arm_version}")

    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${project.slf4j_version}")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${project.logback_version}") {
        exclude group: 'edu.washington.cs.types.checker', module: 'checker-framework'
    }
    implementation("fr.raksrinana:utils.http:${project.raksrinana_utils_version}")

    implementation("com.beust:jcommander:${project.jcommander_version}")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${project.jackson_version}")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${project.jackson_version}")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${project.jackson_version}")
    implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:${project.httpclient_version}")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${project.lang3_version}")
    implementation("org.reflections:reflections:${project.reflections_version}")
    implementation("com.vdurmont:emoji-java:${project.emoji_java_version}")
    implementation("org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:${project.imgscalr_version}")
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url = 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
    maven {
        url = 'https://jcenter.bintray.com'
    }
    maven {
        url = 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/RakSrinaNa/JavaUtils/'
        credentials {
            username buildProperties.secrets['GITHUB_USER'].string
            password buildProperties.secrets['GITHUB_TOKEN'].string
        }
    }
}

import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

processResources {
    doFirst {
        from 'src/main/resources'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [project_version: project.version, project_name: project.name])
    }
}

compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application {
    mainModule = project.moduleName
    mainClass = project.mainClass
}

java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}

shadowJar {
    archivesBaseName = project.name
    classifier = 'shaded'
    archiveVersion = ''
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.deprecation = true
}

tasks.withType(Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = project.wrapper_version
}
```

Though even trying with the one below gives the same error:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

tasks.withType(Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = project.wrapper_version
}
```

EDIT2:
Opened an issue on JB side https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245303

Comment: I had no problem with Gradle 6.5.1 in IJ 2020.1.2. Can you share your build.gradle?

Comment: @TomasZezula I edited the post with the build.gradle. And a minimilistic one that fails too. Though if this works for you then probably I should report it on the Jetbrains side on their youtrack.

Comment: I had no problem with the minimalist build config. I get an error in the actual build.gradle, because it references some custom variables you must have in gradle.properties. Nevertheless, I believe I've found your repo (FileSecure, correct?) and have no issues in building the project with gradle 6.5.1

Comment: It was RSNDiscord but yeah if the minimalist file is working for you and not for me then it's probably a problem on my side with IJ. I'll try to fully clear/reinstall it, and if doesn't work open an issue on their youtrack. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @RakSrinaNa have you fixed the solution, i am facing same issue.

Comment: @kalyani_jamunkar You can look the youtrack link at the end of the original post for details. But to sum it up I didn't really fixed it but found a workaround.

Apparently the fact that I had IJ installed with the toolbox on a drive different than C made it not work (even if reinstalling and all). Installing it on the C drive made it work again.

So it's probably a permission issue on the files or something, but I didn't look more into it after moving it to the C drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a Gradle issue (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17551) that appeared in Gradle 6.5 and is fixed in 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact issue with the newest version of everything - gradle plugin 4.1.2 and Gradle Version 6.5. I have my Windows OS installed on C, and a fresh install of Android Studio (with intellij inside) on a portable hard drive. The project is on the portable hard drive, too.

**It seems that the gradle script unable to locate the package org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder on another disk.**

Install Android Studio on your C drive and, if this is the case, all your problems will go away.